# composer fails to install slim api framework

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, composer-php

Hey guys trying to install the slim php api framework locally via composer but everytime I try to run

```
composer require slim/slim "^3.0"
```

the following error happens:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed

I am doing all of this on my mac running `macOS` and have no idea how to solve this issue can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

It's an OpenSSL issue. You can download root certificates with

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

then edit `openssl.cafile` parameter in your `php.ini` configuration file:

```
openssl.cafile=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

---

If you aren't able to do it you can use composer's `disable-tls` option.

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

*Enabling this is a security risk and is NOT recommended.*

Comment: so i ran `php -i` via cli have the following `Loaded Configuration File:  (none)` but i have this file in my `etc` directory `php.ini.default`

Comment: alright 1 last thing, best recommendation on where to save the cacert.pem file?

Comment: `  [RuntimeException]                     
  The "--cafile" option does not exist. `